# confirm dialog before form submit on click

Tags: jquery, laravel, onclick

I am working with Laravel 5.4. I have a `POST` route:

`Route::post('hotel/delete/{slug}', ['as' => 'delete-hotel', 'uses' => 'Backend\HotelController@postDelete']);`

In index page, I have a anchor tag with form submit. Currently, when anchor tag is clicked, a hidden form is submitted.

```
<a href="{{ route('delete-hotel', $hotel->slug) }}" class="btn btn-operation btn-danger" 
    onclick="event.preventDefault(); 
    document.getElementById('delete-form').submit();"> 
    <i class="fa fa-close"></i> Delete</a> 

<form id="delete-form" action="{{ route('delete-hotel', $hotel->slug) }}" 
    method="post" style="display: none;">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

But, I want to display a confirm dialog. From the user click result, if user click `ok`, delete the item or if user click `cancel`, no action is taken.

Helps are appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use javascript default [**confirm()**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_confirm.asp)

**HTML PART**

```
<a href="{{ route('delete-hotel', $hotel->slug) }}" class="btn btn-operation btn-danger" onclick="return confirmation();">
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function confirmation(){
    if(confirm('are you sure?')){
        document.getElementById('delete-form').submit();
    }else{
        return false;
    }   
}
```

Hope it will help you.

**UPDATE**

May be you are redirecting to `href` url before form submit. So make your link

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-operation btn-danger" onclick="return confirmation();">
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This displays a confirmation dialogue and based on that event, form is submited. But, form is submitted with `GET METHOD`. Any idea?

Comment: Add attribute method="POST" to form

Comment: method is already defined to post, but it is not actually triggered. @sanchit

Comment: try to remove url to `href` tag make it `href="javascript:void(0)"` for testing. Let me update my answer

Comment: Your Welcome @vijayrana! Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

http://bootstrap-confirmation.js.org/

That is a pretty useful tool to use!

Place the code below into the Document ready .

```
    $('[id$="btnDoSomethingDrastic"]').click(function (event) {
    //So when a user clicks the DoSomethingDrastic button....

    event.preventDefault();
    // If one already exists then destroy it
    $(this).confirmation('destroy');

    // Create a new confirmation...
    $(this).confirmation({
        rootSelector: '[data-toggle=confirmation]',
        placement: 'bottom',
        title: 'Action Selected Changes',
        btnOkLabel: 'Action now',
        btnOkIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-share-alt',
        btnOkClass: 'btn-success',
        btnCancelLabel: 'Cancel',
        btnCancelIcon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ban-circle',
        btnCancelClass: 'btn-danger',
        content: 'Are you sure you want to continue:<br><br>This will do something drastic!!!<br><strong>Are you sure you want to do this?</strong>',
        html: true,
        popout: true,

        container: 'body',
        onConfirm: function () {
            //The user confirmed they wanted to do something drastic
            actionGoAndDoSomethingDrastic();
        }
    });

    // ... and show it.
    $(this).confirmation('show');
});
```

Comment: You could probably write something yourself if you wanted to.

Comment: That would be awesome but need some time and effort. will list on TO DO list.

Answer (score 0):

With Jquery (It can be done without, but since it is widely use...) :

```
$(document).on("click", '.delete_button',function() {
    var data = $('#delete-form').serialize();
    slug = $(this).attr('href');
    var confirm = confirm("Are you sure ?");
    if (confirm) {
        $.ajax({
            url: slug,
            type: "get",
            data : 'data',
            success : function(data){
                [Do what you want (checkmark, alert, etc ....)]
            }
        });
    event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain `If you only want to hit a GET route, you don't have to use a form`

Comment: Nevermind, I miss read your code, it appear that you send the form with the link. I edit my answer